# feed dialog is not available?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get the following error after I enter my phone number and password

> Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while
>   processing this request. Please try again later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".facebookLink").on("click", function(){
                // $.ajax({
                //     method
                // })
                var reviewId = $(this).data("id");
                console.log("ReviewID", reviewId)
                var appId = "{myID}" // I use real appId
                var redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/reviewfor/x.com"
                var description = "this is my description";
                var link = "http://localhost:3000/reviewfor/x.com"
                this.href= `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=${appId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&description=${description}&link=${link}`
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <% reviews.forEach(review => { %>
        <div>
        <span>review text : </span> <%= review.reviewText %> <span> ReviewID : <a href = "/review/<%=review._id%>"><%=review._id%></a> </span>
        <a class = "facebookLink" data-id ="<%= review._id%>">share to Facebook</a>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be if you properly implemented Facebook´s SDK for that.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

I believe in your case you want the Share Dialog to apear

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

if true, than the implementation would look like this

```
var link = "http://localhost:3000/reviewfor/x.com"
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: yourLink,
}, function(response){});
```

to be able to call this API properly, be sure to initialize the SDK with `FB.init`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.9

Comment: maybe the problem is I can't use localhost. when I use other sites like google it works. Any comments on that? I thought it would work with localhost. It should shouldn't it?

Comment: Because Facebook will try and request the URL you are sharing, to read the Open Graph meta data from it. That won’t work for localhost URLs.